# Google OCR on perm installation issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to install google's OCR on perm but I getting following error in ocr install service:

> E0820 09:07:22.051148 1 gcs_utils.cc:29] Failed to download: DownloadFileImpl(ReadObjectRangeRequest={bucket_name=vision_onprem_assets, object_name=e2e_line_model/00000785/assets.extra/LabelMap.textproto, disable-md5-hash=1}, /tmp/e2e_line_model/00000785/assets.extra/LabelMap.textproto): cannot open download source object - status.message=Permanent error in Read(): [PERMISSION_DENIED] [PERMISSION_DENIED]

I have setup services Account with browser, edit, owner, viewer export json file and create secret passed to installation.

Is anyone have idea what might be wrong ?

Michal.

Answer (score 0):

When the service-account has role `project/viewer` ...check the bucket's ACL. You'd probably have to set `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json` (if not already done so). And in order to enable RPC logging, set `export CLOUD_STORAGE_ENABLE_CLOG=yes`.

Comment: gsutil acl get gs://vision_onprem_assets reutend 403 AccessDeniedException for user, does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. vision_onprem_assets bucker belongs to google

Comment: Well, the documentation is 404: https://cloud.google.com/vision/on-prem/priv/docs ...while most likely, either the service-account is misconfigured, or you may be using the wrong one service-account altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that purchasing product from google Marketplace isn't enough and that I need to contact Google sales team to be given access to actual solution files which I got issue with in Q.